# partial derivatives under integral sign

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

We have $f(x,y)=\int_{0}^{y^2\sqrt{x}}\sin(t^2)dt$. How does one prove that $f$ is differentiable on $0<x<\infty,-\infty<y<\infty?$ And how does one calculate $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$?

It would be kind if you could tell where to look. My knowledge is of Apostol Calculus 2.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Note this has nothing to do with differentiating *under the integral sign*.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x, y) = g(y^2\sqrt{x})$, where $g(z) = \int_{0}^{z}\sin(t^2)\,dt$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $g'(z) = \sin(z^2)$. Using the chain rule you can now compute the derivatives of $f$.